# Transferring from one ArrayList to another

Tags: java, arraylist, addition, transfer

I'm trying to transfer the contents of `ArrayList purse` to `ArrayList purse2` using the `add` method.

However, when I try to just do `purse2.add(purse)` I get a paragraph of errors.

However, I have figured out that if I do `purse2.add(input)` it should work, but when I do that in my `transfer` method it just adds `"done"` into the array instead any other word that is inputted. If I put this line up with the initial input of `purse` then it works perfectly, except I cannot have the line up there for my output to make any sense.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
package purse;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Purse {
    ArrayList<String> purse = new ArrayList<>(); 
    ArrayList<String> purse2 = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner coin = new Scanner (System.in); 
    Scanner coin2 = new Scanner (System.in);
    String input = " ";
    String input2 = " ";
    String end = "done";

    public void addCoin(){
        System.out.println("Please put as many coins of U.S currency as you like into Jodie's purse, type 'done' when finished: ");

        while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase ("done"))
        {
            input = ( coin.nextLine());
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("penny") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("nickel") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("dime") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("quarter") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                purse.add(input);
                purse2.add(input);
                purse.remove("done");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please input a coin of U.S currency.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Contents of purse: " + purse);
        Collections.reverse(purse);
        System.out.println("This is the contents of the purse reversed: " + purse );

        //Start of Johnny's Purse
        System.out.println("Please put as many coins of U.S currency as you like into Johnny's purse, type 'done' when finished: ");
        while (!input2.equalsIgnoreCase ("done")) {
            input2 = (coin.nextLine());
            if (input2.equalsIgnoreCase("penny") || input2.equalsIgnoreCase("nickel") || input2.equalsIgnoreCase("dime") || input2.equalsIgnoreCase("quarter") || input2.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                purse2.add(input2); 
                purse2.remove("done");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please input a coin of U.S currency.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Contents of purse: " + purse2);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> printPurseContents() {
        return purse;  
    }

    public void transfer() {
        purse.clear();

        System.out.println("Jodie is feeling bad for Johnny so Jodie is going to give him all of her money!");
        System.out.println("Johnny's purse  now has: " + purse2 );
        System.out.println("and now Jodie's pure is empty: " +purse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the exect errors you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

To add the content of a List `l1` into another List `l2` you should use `l2.addAll(l1)`. Using `l2.add(l1)` is wrong because `add()` accepts only one element of the same type of the `List`, that is a String in this case. But you are trying to pass a `List` of `String`s to the `add()` method, so the compiler throws an error.

Comment: This is answer to remaining part of your question. Since the while loop breaks only after you provide "done" to input, so at this time when you insert input into your list after the while loop the obvious happens. As the commenter said you call `add()` for single entry, so that you are able to add input to list but to add an another list you need to call `addAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're attempting the transfer but I assume it will go in your `transfer()` method. What you need to do is loop through `purse`, adding each element to `purse2`, then clear `purse`. (You can't remove the elements from `purse` as you go because you'll run into a `ConcurrentModificationException` from the iterator.)

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do it:
1) Use loops ( for / foreach )
2) Use addAll() method (the best way)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is intended, but when you read the input, each coin added to Jodie's `purse` is immediately added to Johnny's `purse2` as well:

```
purse.add(input);
purse2.add(input); // I think this line should be removed
```

Anyway, when I removed the above mentioned line, all I had to do was to modify the beginning of the `transfer` method accordingly:

```
public void transfer() {
    purse2.addAll(purse);
    purse.clear();
    // the rest of the method follows unchanged
```

I tested these changes with the following code - to me the result seemed correct:

```
Purse p = new Purse();
p.addCoin();
p.transfer();
```